# Do I need to manually close database connections?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, database-connection

I have a shop (Magento 1.9) with ~40.000 products.
Every night they will be imported/updated via cronjob. There are other cronjobs that do various database operations as well.

In my import script there are also custom database connections (`Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')`).

Occasionally when the shop is crowded with visitors the database seems to be blocked with sleeping connections: `General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded`.

I was relying upon magento to take care of the connections but it seems I was mistaken.

Now I am not sure if and at what point (after each use? after the script finished?) I should close those connections manually and what the implications are. Is it ok to simply kill all connections from time to time?

Comment: would magmi not be a better way to update products? https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Comment: That is not the question.